# Count number of occurences group by

Tags: linux, shell, find-occurrences

I need to count the number of times each occurence appear, not only '`group by`' which I make with `sort`:

```
>>> cat /var/log/squid/access.log* | awk '{ print $NF }' | sort -u
TCP_CLIENT_REFRESH_MISS:DIRECT
TCP_DENIED:NONE
TCP_HIT:NONE
TCP_IMS_HIT:NONE
TCP_MEM_HIT:DIRECT
TCP_MEM_HIT:NONE
TCP_MISS:DIRECT
TCP_MISS:NONE
TCP_NEGATIVE_HIT:NONE
TCP_REFRESH_HIT:DIRECT
TCP_REFRESH_MISS:DIRECT
>>>
```

How would you do?

Comment: I don't think there was any need to delete your latest question - it might have been unclear to one or two people, but I'm sure you could have explained it. Deleting a question unnecessarily causes annoyance to people who are in the middle of writing a comment/answer. For reference, my comment response was: "I wonder if implementing Serializable lets it reconstruct things that ordinary serialisation cannot re-initialise, like internal Resources. It might be pertinent to the question though: in what way did your first attempt not work?"

Comment: You're right, I'm going to re-ask it another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort | uniq -c` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @OlivierPons: if the answer is, indeed, perfect, you should consider accepting and upvoting it.

Comment: @Emmet I was almost sleeping on my keyboard at 2'00 so I went to bed, and now it's 8:30 I can check it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk '{a[$NF]++}END{for (i in a) print a[i],i|"sort"}' /var/log/squid/access.log*
```

Comment: Very nice awk suggestion